# Changing a players game mode when they stand on colored wool

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The command I've been using so far is

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:wool 14 game mode adventure
```

to set a players game mode to adventure when they step on Red wool. For some reason the command block output says

> Failed to execute 'detect' as MyUsername

I've tried plugging in different id's but I seem to be getting the same error. If someone could point out what I'm doing wrong I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were probably not standing on red wool at the time the command was run.  It will give that "error" when the detect portion fails.

Your command has a problem as well.  There should be no space in game mode and [gamemode command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#gamemode) should have a target.  Use @s as it will target whoever executed the command.

Functioning command if player is on red wool:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:wool 14 gamemode adventure @s
```

Another addition is you could exclude players who are already in [adventure mode in the target selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_game_mode):

```
/execute @a[m=!adventure] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:wool 14 gamemode adventure @s
```

Here is the corrected command while not standing on red wool:
[image: Failed to detect]

Success:
[image: Success]

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute as @a positioned as @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:red_wool run gamemode adventure @s`